# Universal Windows app, phone only?

Tags: windows, mobile, universal

This is kind of a weird question, I know, but is there a way to limit a Windows 10 Universal app to run only on Windows 10 Mobile? The app I am making has no use on a device that is not a phone (it is for the Microsoft Band, so nothing but a phone).

Comment: Wouldn't it then... *not* be "universal"?  Or am I missing something.

Comment: Hence the question being weird.. but there is no SDK for Windows 10 Mobile only, that I've been able to locate.

Answer (score 0):

in the code-view of your package.appxmanifest you can set, on which device families your app should be available.

```
<Dependencies>
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile"
minVersion="10.1.0.0" maxVersionTested="10.2.0.0" /></Dependencies>
```

With this entry, the app just runs on Windows.Mobile devices (phones).If you want or need: In this section you can setup a mix of device families and minimum versions. Example:

```
<Dependencies>
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" minVersion="10.2.0.0" maxVersionTested="10.4.0.0"/>
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" minVersion="10.0.10240.0" maxVersionTested="10.5.0.0" /> </Dependencies>
```